# Unable to call Mapper.xml file by using junit testing for the application developed using Mybatis+Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-boot-test, spring-mybatis

I'm very new to junit testing. How to write junit test real database call from mybatis.xml file.
Please find the below code.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@MybatisTest
@SpringBootTest
public class HotelMapperTest {

  @Autowired
  private HotelMapper hotelMapper;

  @Test
  public  void selectByCityIdTest() {
    Hotel hotel = hotelMapper.selectByCityId(1);
    assertThat(hotel.getName()).isEqualTo("Conrad Treasury Place");
    assertThat(hotel.getAddress()).isEqualTo("William & George Streets");
    assertThat(hotel.getZip()).isEqualTo("4001");
  }
```

when i run the junit testing i'm getting below exception:
**org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found):**

Herer my question is how we'll test  the real database, When enable the **@MybatisTest** it's looking for datasource, already we specified all properties in applicaiton.properties. In this time i'm getting below exception:
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource':**

Comment: BindingException means the mapper interface can't find the sql in xml.show more details about  your configration in your applicaton

Comment: Could you provide a small reproduce project?

Answer (score 2):

You can config mybatis mapper location in spring configuration file (such as application.yml).

mybatis configuration:

```
mybatis:
  mapper-locations:
    - classpath*:mapper/*.xml
```